# How to change a SystemParameter on the OS level?

Tags: wpf, windows

I learned to in order to pick up System Parameter one should use dynamic resources. I take this XAML as an example:

```
   <Grid
    Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowFrameBrushKey} }"
    >
    <Button
        Width="100" Height="50"
        Content="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.IconWidthKey} }"
        />
</Grid>
```

How would I change these values, e.g. WindowFrameBrushKey in Windows 10 to see the effect on my program? I tried Settings -> Personalize -> Colors -> Choose accent color, but no success.

Comment: According to (this)[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.systemcolors.windowframebrushkey?view=netcore-3.1#System_Windows_SystemColors_WindowFrameBrushKey], the property gets the windows frame color, so you can change this in the settings options for Windows 10 (review this link: https://www.howtogeek.com/353204/how-to-customize-window-borders-and-shadows-on-windows-10/). Is this working for you?

Comment: No, does not help. As said above, I can change the accent color without an effect on my program.

Answer (score 0):

The WindowFrameBrushKey is getting its value from the Windows registry. I'm writing this solution from [this](https://winaero.com/blog/change-window-frame-color-in-windows-10/) post:

1. Open the Registry Editor (regedit)
2. Go to the Registry key: "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Colors" and search the string value WindowFrame
3. The value is in the "Red[space]Green[space]Blue" format. Change to the value you need.
4. Sign out and then sign in to make the changes apply.

Comment: I am using DynamicResource to react on changes while my program runs. That was the recommendation, e.g. here: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/how-to-use-system-parameters-keys.
What I am looking for is how I can change such a parameter *while my program runs*

Comment: The documentations mention SystemParameters, no SystemColors. I used in my projects teh SystemParameters, but never SystemColors. Maybe (but not sure), that's why you can't update your app colors while it's running.